# Having Arrays as the value of a field v13 gives an error

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I created this command that utilizes Embeds, it used columns where I could input strings. It achived this by having the value as an array. But in V13 this doesn't seem to work, it keeps coming up with the same error:

> RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings

How the embed looked like V12:

[image: Discord Embed]

V12 code:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Embed Title")
        .setColor("DC143C")
        .addFields(
            { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
            { name: "Field 1:", value: `Value`, inline: true },
            { name: "Field 2:", value: `Value`, inline: true },
            { name: "Field 3:", value: `Value`, inline: true },
            { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
            {
                name: `Column 1`,
                value: ["word", "word", "word", "word", "word"],
                inline: true,
            },
            {
                name: `Column 2`,
                value: ["word", "word", "word", "word", "word"],
                inline: true,
            },
            {
                name: `Column 3`,
                value: ["word", "word", "word", "word", "word"],
                inline: true,
            }
        );
```

How can I achive the same thing in Discord.JS v13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Embed Title")
        .setColor("DC143C")
        .addFields(
            { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
            { name: "Field 1:", value: `Value`, inline: true },
            { name: "Field 2:", value: `Value`, inline: true },
            { name: "Field 3:", value: `Value`, inline: true },
            { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
            {
                name: `Column 1`,
                value: ["word", "word", "word", "word", "word"].join('\n'),
                inline: true,
            },
            {
                name: `Column 2`,
                value: ["word", "word", "word", "word", "word"].join('\n'),
                inline: true,
            },
            {
                name: `Column 3`,
                value: ["word", "word", "word", "word", "word"].join('\n'),
                inline: true,
            }
        );
```

Now only strings can be field values, see https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#strings

Comment: Sorry if I am dumb. But I see no difference between my code and that code. I also don't really understand what you mean with "Adding a space will make the string non-empty". Where Should I add the space?

Comment: @KraftaN in "\u200B", make it into "\u200B ", or just copy paste my code

Comment: Or just change "\u200B" to " " in the value of the field( not the name )

Comment: Oh I think you are misunderstanding my problem. In V13 this code doesn't work because I have Arrays in values. Try using your code in V13. It won't work. Look at the Column 1, 2 and three. That is the part which yields a probem in V13.

Comment: @KraftaN sorry, I misunderstood the problem, I have now edited my answer and checked the Upgrade Guide from discord.js. I have linked the explanation

Comment: Solutions without an explanation of what is actually changed, and importantly why, are not very valuable. People should not have to be human diff tools to look for changes

Comment: @charlietfl The error itself is self explanatory, and the link I gave shows the exact reason why it is like this.

Comment: That means your answer relies solely on explanation from a link and does not stand alone without that link. That is not how SO is intended to work. Links should only support what is explicitly shown in an answer. The explanation of "Try" is meaningless. Is it really that much trouble to explain "change X to Y for ____ reason"?

Comment: @charlietfl so, the "link" is the official guide and documentation for discord.js. Should I have copy pasted a part of it for nothing instead of actually giving the source. Also my explanation is at the bottom which is "now only strings can be field values" and this statement is backed up by the reference to the discord.js official migration changes between v12 and v13

Comment: Like I already mentioned a simple explanation of what you changed and why goes a very long way to explaining the problem and solution. An answer should completely stand on it's own without the supporting link. Links can rot in the futire